# serialization c# object collection, how to get just certain property of references object?

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization

this is the class:

```
 public class Category
 {
     public guid id,
     public string name,
     public Category Parent            
 }
```

i am using  Json.net to serialize a collection of it, but i don't want the Parent object to be serialized, just need the id:
   what i expecte:

```
 [
  {'name':'cate1','id':1000,'parent':999}
  {'name':'cate2','id':1001,'parent':998}
 ]
```

i have read about the [Serialization Attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) but don't get a solution.

Comment: Do you need to deserialize also, converting ID back to parent while reading?

Comment: @dbc no need. just need the parent_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a get-only property for the parent id (private or public as you prefer), and serialize that, ignoring the actual `Parent` property:

```
public class Category
{
    public int id;

    public string name;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Category Parent;

    [JsonProperty("parent", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    int? ParentId { get { return Parent == null ? (int?)null : Parent.id; } }
}
```